# How to increase resolution on latest Raspbian Pixel while connected to VNC client?

Tags: vnc

I downloaded and dd latest image of Raspbian Pixel on sdcard of Raspberry Pi 3. I activated VNC interface from Menu> Preferences> Raspberry Pi Configuration. Raspberry Pi is connected to the wifi and I access it on my iPad mini using VNC Viewer app. Also no HDMI is connected to Pi.

Now the problem is I only get resolution of 656x416 which is too small for doing stuff. Since I didn't manually edit any file using terminal, I don't know how to increase it. I think I need to edit a vnc file and pass parameters. Please help me fix resolution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found a fix, edited /boot/config.txt

enabled these configs:

```
framebuffer_width=1280
framebuffer_height=720
```

Note - on some versions of Pixel you may need to create this file as it may not exist.  For example using a Kali Linux version and this file did not exist but worked for a headless implementation once created after a reboot.

Answer (score 15):

In the desktop menu, go to Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration and click the "Set Resolution" button. Or, from the terminal, run sudo raspi-config and choose Advanced Options > Resolution.

If you have a monitor attached, it will show a list of modes supported by the monitor. If you don't have a monitor attached, it will show a list of the most common modes.

If you want a mode that isn't listed, you will need to edit /boot/config.txt as described here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

You will need to reboot your Pi for the new mode to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

Increase frame buffer in configs file:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

by uncommenting these lines:

```
framebuffer_width=1280
framebuffer_height=720
```

and then

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Is this the same answer as from Karanvir?